# Warning in table view

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, uitableview

I'm using the table view in the view controller, with the simple array was displayed in the list. That array was displays and works fine but I'm getting this warning. May I know the reason for this and please some ideas to rectify this issues..

> WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of
>   tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in .  Please remove your implementation of this method and set
>   the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move
>   to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called
>   in a future release.

Thanks

Comment: Until you have accepted some answers to your previous questions I wont even read your question :)

Comment: Hi  willcodejavaforfood 
Pls guide me how to accept the answer.i cant get you wat you mean...

Answer (score 3):

The method `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` is deprecated in iPhone OS 3.0. Delete the implementation of this method and add the following code in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` :

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

See `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` in the documentation for other type.

Comment: Hi Mathieuf due to there is no enough space,i have answered in the answer tab pls,chk my code .wher im making the mistake
Thanks for your advice!!!

Comment: Have you deleted the method tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: ?

Comment: ya i have deleted MathieuF now its not showing that warning,thanks a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

Im using the following code as you mentioned :

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    cell.text = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;
}
```

But it returns the same

Answer (score 0):

Its just saying that this method is about to disappear in next version, so you should go to documentations look for tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath and surely you will find alternative ways of doing what you want you want to do.

In other words, set the accessory of that cell by calling UITableViewCell accessory-view and accessory-type properties

```
myCell.accessoryType = ...
myCell.accessoryView = ...
```

Comment: Hi Nacho due to there is no enough space,i have answered in the answer tab pls,chk my code .wher im making the mistake
Thanks for your advice!!!